# IndexError: too many indices for array - Total Energy Matrix Variational Method

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, physics

I'm trying to define an array for total energy (H) where the following relationship is true:

< i | H | j > = E_j < i | j > =  E_j * S[ i , j ]

and S[ i , j ] is the corresponding element of the overlap matrix. I have the matrix E_j and I am trying to obtain the matrix H as follows:

```
H = np.zeros([M])
for n in range (M):
    for m in range(M):
        H[n,m]= E[n]*S[n,m]
print ("H = ")
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, H, fmt= '%7.4f')
```

This gives me the error message: "IndexError: too many indices for array"

which I'm assuming has something to do with the fact that I've tried to multiply a one dimensional array by a two dimensional array. Not really sure if there is a workaround for this but any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the initialization be `H = np.zeros([M,M])` instead?

Comment: @Divakar Oh yes you're right! Thank you for pointing out my silly mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with NumPy arrays, I would suggesting looking into vectorized methods to boost performance. In your case, you could convert `E` to `2D` by introducing a singleton dimension as the second one with [`numpy.newaxis/None`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and then perform the element-wise multiplication with `S`. This would bring in [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), which would under the hood replicate all elements of `E` to the shape of `S`, which is a very efficient operation and thereafter multiply with `S`.

So, we would have a one-liner to get `H`, like so -

```
H = E[:,None]*S
```

We could also use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) and this might look very close to the original loopy form with iterators *morphed* as strings, like so -

```
H = np.einsum('n,nm->nm',E,S)
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialization of the H matrix was incorrect. Should be as follows:

```
H = np.zeros([M,M])
for n in range (M):
    for m in range(M):
        H[n,m]= E[n]*S[n,m]
print ("H = ")
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, H, fmt= '%7.4f')
```